# Parsing a file with column data in Python

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a file that contains the symbol table `details.Its` in the form of rows and columns.

I need to extract first and last column.

How can I do that?

Comment: You're going to need to describe the format of your "symbol table" file in more detail. Is it text? Are the "rows" terminated by line breaks (\n)? How are the columns separated? Fixed width? Commas? Semicolons? Tabs?

Comment: columns are seperated with space

Comment: Please edit the question to add new facts, @rejinacm.

Comment: You should edit your question and put a little sample of the file in order to let we know how the file really is. It's too vague.

Answer (score 14):

[csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv) module is the easier way.
You can use any separator with this code:

```
import csv

def import_text(filename, separator):
    for line in csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=separator, 
                           skipinitialspace=True):
        if line:
            yield line

for data in import_text('somefile.txt', '/'):
    print (data)
```

Comment: What does "if line" do? Skip empty lines?

Answer (score 5):

What type of delimiter are you using?  That is, what separates your columns?

I'll assume you're using comma delimiters, like so:

```
col1,  col2,  col3
col11, col12, col13
col21, col22, col23
col31, col32, col33
```

The following code will parse it and print the first and last columns of each row:

```
# open file to read
f = file('db.txt', 'r')

# iterate over the lines in the file
for line in f:
    # split the line into a list of column values
    columns = line.split(',')
    # clean any whitespace off the items
    columns = [col.strip() for col in columns]

    # ensure the column has at least one value before printing
    if columns:
        print "first", columns[0]  # print the first column
        print "last", columns[-1] # print the last column
```

Comment: For csv files, you should be using the csv module.

Comment: @Aaron, the author didn't specify that he's using CSV, so Soviut presented a good solution because it shows what is going on and therefore can be modified more easily.

Comment: @Soviut: Using "," is confusing, since CSV is well-defined and isn't this.  Using " " is a better choice because it doesn't overlap CSV.

Answer (score 5):

The most convenient way of parsing tables written to text files is using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). It supports any delimiter and is more convenient to use than manual line-by-line parsing. Example:

```
import csv

def get_first_and_last_column(filename, separator):
    with file(filename, 'rb') as file_obj:
        for line in csv.reader(file_obj, 
              delimiter=separator,    # Your custom delimiter.
              skipinitialspace=True): # Strips whitespace after delimiter.
            if line: # Make sure there's at least one entry.
                yield line[0], line[-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for pair in get_first_and_last_column(r'c:\temp\file.txt', ';'):
        print pair
```

Now, if you give it a file like this:

```
Edgar; Alan; Poe
John; Smith

Lots;   of;   whitespace; here
```

It will produce the following output:

```
('Edgar', 'Poe')
('John', 'Smith')
('Lots', 'here')
```

**EDIT**: custom parameters to `csv.reader` can be passed as keyword arguments, too (thanks, nosklo!).

Comment: It is needlessy complex - If you're doing something simple, you don't have to create a new dialect, just pass the params: csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True).

Answer (score 0):

According to the update, columns are seperated with space. So it would be:

```
rawfile = open('details.Its', 'r')
table = [line.rstrip().split() for line in rawfile.readlines()]

newtable = [[line[0]]+[line[-1]] for line in table]
print(newtable)
```